# In SO anonymously, right-clicking link won't allow mouse into context menu

Tags: support, status-norepro, user-interface, hyperlinks, anonymous

I entered SO through a Google search on a browser that I wasn't signed into SO on.  I didn't bother signing in, then found a link I wanted to pursue.  I right-clicked on the link, so that I could open it in another tab, but when I went into the context menu, it dissapeared.

Note that simultaneously, the `Was this post useful to you` line blinked (may not be directly related).

Comment: Browser: FF 6.0.2

Comment: No repro with FF7 or Chrome13.

Comment: Sidenote: If the context-menu would be deactivated via JavaScript, it would not show up at all. After it is shown, it is handled by Firefox and the underlying OS.

Comment: This is because Jeff and co. want to prevent their logo from being stolen. Putting it into a CSS sprite was only the first step; this is the second. As the final step, the logo will be put inside a signed Java Applet that terminates all screenshot apps, and  freezes the `PrintScreen` key.

Answer (score 1):

We can't reproduce the behavior you are describing.